# Самый быстрый факториал

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Столкнулся с интересной задачкой. Как посчитать факториал числа самым быстрым способом? Быстрее чем за O(n). Подкиньте идею.

Comment: Один раз вычисляем факториал до гуглпекса(любым способом) - сохраняем куда-нибудь - потом пользуемся всю жизнь. Вычисление за 0(1). =)

Comment: Формулу Муавра—Стирлинга пробовали употребить?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Типы со знаком (signed)

Самый быстрый алгоритм вычисления факториала числа с типом `int` - это использование таблицы. Так как переполнение `int` приводит к неопределенному поведению (UB), то максимальное значение факториала ограничено INT_MAX.

Для 32-разрядного `int` максимальный факториал это `fac(12) = 479001600`, по этому самая быстрая функция вычисления факториала `int32_t` выглядит так:

```
std::int32_t fac(std::int32_t x) {
    static const int table[] = {
        1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600,
    };
    assert(x >= 0);
    assert(x <= 12);
    return table[x];
}
```

### Типы без знака (unsigned)

Для `unsigned int` всё интереснее, он может переполняться, но `fac(34)` имеет множитель 2^32:

```
fac(34) = 0xde1bc4d19efcac82445da75b'0000'0000
```

Поэтому начиная с 34 все результаты `fac(uint32_t)` будут равны нулю.

### 64-разрядные типы

Для 64-разрядных чисел переполнение происходит после `fac(20)`, нули начиная с `fac(66)`.

Таким образом, использование таблицы факториалов из 66 элементов покроет всех типы до 64 разрядов:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

// Таблица длинная, по этому посчитаем ее во время компиляции (С++14).
template<int N>
struct Table {
    constexpr Table() : t() {
        t[0] = 1;
        for (auto i = 1; i < N; ++i)
            t[i] = t[i - 1] * i; 
    }
    std::uint64_t t[N];
};

template<typename T>
T fac(T x) {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(std::uint64_t), "T is too large");
    constexpr auto table = Table<66>();
    assert(x >= 0);
    return x < 66 ? static_cast<T>(table.t[x]) : 0;
}

int main() {    
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i != 70; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << fac(i) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Вот есть [интересная статейка](https://www.cecm.sfu.ca/%7Epborwein/PAPERS/P29.pdf). Там предлагают считать факториал за `O(loglogn*M(nlogn))` (где `M(n)` — время перемножения двух n-значных чисел). Быстрее вряд ли получится.

Также гляньте вот [эту статью](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/modular_factorial) — там считают факториал по простому модулю.

Answer (score 13):

Самый быстрый факториал - факториал, посчитанный во время компиляции программы. В С++ для этого можно использовать шаблоны. Взял и скопипастил пример сюда:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct Factorial
{
 enum { value = N * Factorial<N-1>::value };
};

template<>
struct Factorial<1>
{
 enum { value = 1 };
};

int main()
{
 // Example use
 const int fact5 = Factorial<5>::value;
 std::cout << fact5;
 return 0;
}
```

PS: из недостатков конкретно этого вариант - очень быстро можешь вылезть за пределы допустимых значений для встроенных типов. enum же вроде как int работает.

Comment: Только вместо того, чтобы громоздить шаблоны, здесь можно сделать константный массив. Он не такой большой, чтобы его было сложно сделать, потому что при больших значениях будет переполнение.

    unsigned int factorials[]={1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040 /*..и т. д.*/};

 Этот код ведь компактнее?

Answer (score 11):

Есть интересные материалы по этому поводу. 
Во-первых, есть [калькулятор факториалов на JavaScript](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/fffcalc.html). Он мгновенно вычисляет факториалы чисел до 9.999.999.999

Там же есть материалы по алгоритмам факториалов:
http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm. Я думаю, тут действительно хорошие алгоритмы ;)

На этом же сайте описывается некий метод, который, как я понял использовался в калькуляторах HP. Некий [RPN-калькулятор](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/RPNFactorial.html).

Answer (score 6):

Думаю, что самый быстрый алгоритм вычисления факториала определяется структурой вычислительных средств.
Например, формула Стирлинга допускает представление вида
n! ~ S(n) *= a(n/e)<sup>**n+½**</sup>*, где *a=* sqrt *(2·pi·e)*.
log<sub>2</sub> S(n) = ((*n*+½)( ln *n* - 1 ) + ln *a)·* log<sub>2</sub>e = L(n), S(n)= exp ({L(n)}·ln2)·2 <sup>[L(n)]</sup>.
При этом двоичная запись факториала оканчивается на *B(n)=[n/2]+[n/2<sup>2</sup>]+[n/2<sup>3</sup>]+...* нулей (например, *B(2<sup>k</sup>)=[2<sup>k</sup>/2]+[2<sup>k</sup>/2<sup>2</sup>]+...+2+1 = 2<sup>k</sup>-1*), и поэтому множитель при ней целый.

В итоге получаем формулу для быстрого факториала как целого числа с бинарным масштабным коэффициентом.
n! = [*a*·exp(L(n)·ln2)·2<sup>L(n)-B(n)</sup>+½]·2<sup>B(n)</sup>,
которая при правильно выбранной точности вычислений будет точной.

Answer (score 0):

Ну я такой вариант сочинил.

```
int factorial(int n) {
        int f = 1;

        while (n > 1) {
                for(int i=3;i<=n;i+=2) 
                        f *= i;
                n >>= 1;
                f <<= n;
        }

        return f;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Вопрос очень быстро решается при помощи гугла, ответ взят с сайта algolist.manual.ru:

> Обращаю внимание на то, что при
> вычислениях происходит
> последовательное умножение длинного
> числа на обычное (из базового типа
> данных, например, long int). В
> результате алгоритм умножения имеет
> сложность O(m), m - длина числа, и
> прост в реализации.
>
> ```
> #include "lip.h"
>
> #define FACTSIZE 20000
>
> void main()
> {
>   long i;
>   verylong a=0,b=0;
>
>   zstart();
>   zintoz(1, &a);
>
>   for(i=1;i<=FACTSIZE;i++) zsmul( a, i, &a);
>
>   printf("length = %ld",(long)zslog(a, 10) +1);
>
> }
> ```
>
> © Radionov Alexey
>
> Вот приближение десятичного логарифма
> факториала:
>
> ```
> #include <math.h>
> double log10factorial(double n)
> {
> return((-log(902961561600.0)+log(2.0)/2.0+log(0.3141592653589793E1)/2.0
> +log(902961561600.0*n*n*n*n*n*n*n+75246796800.0*n*n*n*n*n*n
> +3135283200.0*n*n*n*n*n-2421135360.0*n*n*n*n-207204480.0*n*n*n
> +707957280.0*n*n+62961828.0*n-534703531.0)-13.0/2.0*log(n)
> +n*log(n)-n)/log(10.0));
> }
> ```
>
> Целая часть этого покажет количество
> знаков числа-1, а с мантиссой можно
> работать.
>
> Можно вычислять факториал как eln(n!),
> и это будет быстрее, чем прямое
> умножение. Но это не будет точное
> значение для больших значений n, где
> есть реальный выигрыш в скорости.
>
> Тем не менее, часто(например, в
> вычислении биномиальных коэффициентов)
> нам нужен не сам факториал, а некое
> значение, получающееся в результате
> деления громадного факториала на
> другие числа того же порядка, и в
> результате получается небольшое число.
>
> В этом случае имеет смысл оперировать
> именно с логарифмом факториала,
> который вычисляется (как видно,
> например, из исходника выше) гораздо
> проще и быстрее. Деление и умножение
> будут заменены разностью и суммой
> логарифмов. Если нужны реально
> эффективные вычисления, то такой путь
> при контроле точности вычислений,
> безусловно, предпочтительнее.

Comment: Интересно, а какая сложность получается у данного алгоритма? Это явно не константа, но и не O(n).

Comment: Я, конечно, прошу прощения, но сложность здесь O(n) * перемножение двух чисел… Э-э-э… и зачем было отвечать на вопрос, если не поняли, что спрашивают? И своего ответа тоже не поняли…

Comment: >Вопрос очень быстро решается при помощи гугла

 Только вот ты какой-то не тот вопрос решаешь.

Answer (score -3):

Во-первых, надо отказаться от рекурсии: не будет накладных расходов на разворачивание и сворачивание стека.

Во-вторых, можно сделать многопоточность: заюзать стока ядер,сколько есть в ядре - выйдет O(n)/число ядер. Например, 2 ядра и факториал 100: первый поток `1*2*...*50`; второй поток `51*52*...100`, потом перемножить результат.
В-третьих, развивая идею номер 2, можно составить статический массив с уже вычисенными факториалами (его шаг деления и количество элементов влияют на общую скорость в целом)

```
1 => 1!
10 => 10!
10 => 100!
...
```

Надо сосчитать факториал 102, берем уже сосчитанный факториал 100, умножаем его на 101 и на 102, - быстро !!!

А вообще, все 3 метода сразу - будет довольно шустро !!!

Кстати, можно составить массив не во время компиляции, а при работе программы. Например, при статической компиляции было в массиве 2 значения: 1! и 10! а надо сосчитать 102! Мы его считаем и потом добавляем в массив факториал 100! Вдруг нам надо будет считать 105!

Comment: Думаю, вычислять рекурсивно никому в голову бы и не пришло. Предподсчёт некоторых значений не вносит вообще никакого улучшения, когда вычисляется один факториал. Естественно, если надо вычислить несколько факториалов последовательно, то можно сохранить предыдующие результаты и это ваще будет работать за амортизированную единицу! Распараллеливание — это ухищрение, а вопрос-то алгоритмический, а не практический.

Comment: Вопрос алгоритмический, но носит прикладной характер.

Comment: @Матроскин в таком случае, соберите воедино все предложенные оптимизации :).

Comment: @kirelagin А что значит "вычислять рекурсивно никому бы в голову и не пришло"? М.б. данный вопрос зависит от транслятора (tail-call optimisation)?

Comment: @alexlz Метку C++ на вопросе видите?

Comment: @kirelagin Да, вижу. Жду продолжения вопроса.

Comment: Создание и синхронизация потоков будут стоить гораздо дороже, чем само вычисление. Тем более, что очень быстро возникает переполнение. Если бы был факториал 10000, тогда может быть это что-нибудь бы и дало.