# Как посчитать на языке C факториал?

Tags: c

Подскажите как посчитать и вывести на экран факториал , через return?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2479/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB?rq=1 посмотрите там алгоритм и попробуйте реализовать, если будет не получаться - поправьте вопрос

Comment: Посчитать-то несложно... но вот как заставить собаку мяукать?...

Answer (score 1):

Просто посчитать -

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int resulr = 1;
    if (n > 1)
        while(n > 1)
            res *= n--;
    return res;
}
```

Но оператор `return` для вывода на экран не предназначен; воспользуйтесь, например, функцией `printf`.

Answer (score -2):

Вообщем нужно через if вписывается значение nb < 1
Где nb это факториал , и тогда все завершается а else 
nb >1 и тогда n++
В конце в инте на выходе return nb ;

Comment: 8-0   И как, `return` таки выполняет вывод на экран?

Comment: Это не ответ. Воспользуйтесь кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/699314/edit) и редактируйте вопрос.

Comment: да не проблема через return вывести. Либо так  `return printf(...);`, либо `return factorial(n);`, а потом в консоле уже `echo $?`.